# Smarty code converting to PHP code

Tags: php, html, joomla, smarty

I am new to Smarty code and was just wondering if you can provide me with PHP equivalent to this piece of smart code..

```
    <div class = "span3">
        <a href = "{$auction->get('links.details')}"><div id="raffle-list-img">
        {if $current_item->get('imagecount')}
    {$current_item->get('gallery')}
{/if}
</div></a>
    </div>
```

This was in a .tpl file and I need it placing in a .php file.

Im trying to make an auction item to show a photo.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Smarty is very close to standard PHP, so you can normally do an almost direct conversion between the two:

```
<div class="span3">
    <a href="<?php $auction->get('links.details') ?>">
        <div id="raffle-list-img">
        <?php
            if( $current_item->get('imagecount') ) {
                echo $current_item->get('gallery');
            }
        ?>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

I reformatted/reindented to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

well actually it won't be much more readable but I believe it will look like that : `<div class = "span3">
        <a href = "<?php $auction->get('links.details'); ?>"><div id="raffle-list-img">
        <?php if ($current_item->get('imagecount')) {
    $current_item->get('gallery');
} ?>
</div></a>
    </div>`